# Difference between if ("a" or "b" or "c") in X:----- if "a" in x or "b" in x or "c" in x: (python)

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

My question is it:

for me, these two options should do the same thing:

1)

```
if "a" in x or "b" in x or "c" in x:
  print ("xxxxxxxxx")
```

2)

```
if ("a" or "b" or "c") in X:
   print ("xxxxxxxx")
```

but when I run them the results are diferents. The first option work good for me, but the second no. I want print "xxxxx" if a or b or c is in x.

where is the problem???

thanks

Comment: The second one is completely invalid. Use the first until you learn the more succinct methods.

Comment: Very similar to [How do I test one variable against multiple values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values) Not an exact duplicate, but the lesson from it applies here.

Comment: Why? `or` isn't a Boolean operator. `"a" or "b" or "c"` evalutes to `"a"`, and `or` is also not part of the `in` operator, so there's no reason for it to distribute like you want.

Comment: @Carcigenicate It's not at all invalid; it simply doesn't do what the OP expects.

Comment: @chepner Invalid in the sense that it doesn't do as they want. Yes, it's syntactically valid.

Comment: Try `if any(map(lambda i: i in x, ("a", "b", "c"))):`

Comment: Suppose `x` is `['b', 'c']`. Then `("a" in x or "b" in x or "c" in x)` is equivalent to `("a" in ['b', 'c'] or "b" in ['b', 'c'] or "c" in ['b', 'c'])` which is equivalent to `(False or True or True)` which is equivalent to `True`. On the other hand, `(("a" or "b" or "c") in x)` is equivalent to `("a" in ['b', 'c'])` (because of [the way OR works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213535/using-and-and-or-operator-with-python-strings#19213583)) which is equivalent to `False`