# Booleans interpretted from strings, unexpected behavior

Tags: python

Can anyone explain this behaviour in Python (2.7 and 3)

```
>>> a = "Monday" and "tuesday"
>>> a
'tuesday'             # I expected this to be True
>>> a == True
False                 # I expected this to be True
>>> a is True
False                 # I expected this to be True
>>> a = "Monday" or "tuesday"
>>> a
'Monday'              # I expected this to be True
>>> a == True
False                 # I expected this to be True
>>> a is True
False                 # I expected this to be True
```

I would expect that because I am using logic operators `and` and `or`, the statements would be evaluated as `a = bool("Monday") and bool("tuesday")`.

So what is happening here?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-43-logical-operators-on-string-in-python/ this may help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using "and" and "or" operator with Python strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213535/using-and-and-or-operator-with-python-strings)

Comment: The `and` and `or` operators do not return `boolean` objects, they return either of their arguments (which could be anything)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Python support short-circuiting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580136/does-python-support-short-circuiting)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, it appears you are right. It just seems so unintuitive... To me, `and` and `or` are functions that take 2 `bools` and return a `bool`. But I guess I had the wrong intuition. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19213583/3512538) using `and / or` on strings will yield the following result:

- `a or b` returns a if a is True, else returns b.
- `a and b` returns b if a is True, else returns a.

*This behavior is called [Short-circuit_evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) and it applies for both `and, or` as can be seen [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not).*

This explains why `a == 'tuesday'` in the *1st* case and `'Monday'` in the *2nd*.

As for checking `a == True`, `a is True`, using logical operators on strings yields a specific result (as explained in above), and it is not the same as `bool("some_string")`.

Comment: I expected the result of `"monday" and "tuesday"` to be a `bool`, In my mind (and I guess whoever wrote most of the other languages) `and` is an (overloaded) operator that returns a `bool`. Thanks for the explanation