# How to perform AND operator to search with one or more parameters in a file lines ?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to create a python script able to search with one or more parameters in a file lines but after many test I'm not able to do this 
This is my python code:

```
for log_files in os.listdir(path): 
files = os.path.join(path, log_files)
strng = open(files)
for lines in strng.readlines():
            lines = re.sub('"','', lines)
            if (sys.argv[2] and sys.argv[3]) in lines:
                # if sys.argv[3] in lines:
                # print("Matched !!")
                lines=log_files+"__"+lines
                print(lines)
                content_array.append(lines)
```

The code shows me a result which means that it did not take into consideration the two parameters in the if statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is in if condition

```
 if (sys.argv[2] and sys.argv[3]) in lines:
```

It should be

```
if sys.argv[2] in lines and sys.argv[3] in lines:
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213535/using-and-and-or-operator-with-python-strings) for reference

Other possible solution is to use [all()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all).

```
arg_list = [sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3]]
for lines in strng.readlines():
    if all(arg in lines for arg in arg_list):
        print(lines)
```