# Replace lists in text with python regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to replace two lists a text:

```
text = "today is friday july 1 2018"

days = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday']
daysRegex = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, days)))

months =  ['january', 'february', 'march', 'april', 'may', 'mai', 'june', 'july', 'august', 'september', 'october', 'november', 'december']
monthsRegex = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, months)))

replaces = daysRegex.sub("<day>", text) and monthsRegex.sub("<month>", text) 

print(replaces)
```

**output:**

> today is friday < month> 1 2018

**correct output:**

> today is < day>  < month> 1 2018

I'm not sure I'm using the **and** operator correctly. I'm just trying to put into practice what I studied about it (but I may have misunderstood)

Comment: Have you seen this question on 'and' and 'or'? - https://stackoverflow.com/q/19213535/2125723

Answer (score 2):

Since you need to replace 2 value you can do..

**Demo:**

```
import re
text = "today is friday july 1 2018"

days = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday']
daysRegex = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, days)))
months =  ['january', 'february', 'march', 'april', 'may', 'mai', 'june', 'july', 'august', 'september', 'october', 'november', 'december']
monthsRegex = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, months)))
replaces = daysRegex.sub("<day>", monthsRegex.sub("<month>", text))

print(replaces)
```

*or*

```
text = monthsRegex.sub("<month>", text)
replaces = daysRegex.sub("<day>", text)
print(replaces)
```

**Output:**

```
today is <day> <month> 1 2018
```

Answer (score 2):

You indeed misuse the `and` operator, I suggest reading this post to understand your error: [Using "and" and "or" operator with Python strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213535/using-and-and-or-operator-with-python-strings)

You should be applying the second `sub` on the result of the first one such as follows :

```
replaces = daysRegex.sub("<day>", monthsRegex.sub("<month>", text))
```

You will get the correct output then.