# How to concatenate a string returned by a lambda with other strings?

Tags: python, string, lambda, concatenation, string-concatenation

I'm trying to use a `lambda` to check if an object (`self`)'s attribute `problematic_object` is `None`. If it is, it should return a `""` (an empty string), and if not, `str(self.problematic_object)`. I've tried doing it in 3 ways:

1:

```py
def __str__(self):
    return "string1" + str(self.object) + "\n" + "string2" + self.another_object + "\n" + "string3" + exec(lambda self: str(self.problematic_object) if self.problematic_object!=None else "")
```

2:

```py
def __str__(self):
    return "string1" + str(self.object) + "\n" + "string2" + self.another_object + "\n" + "string3" + (lambda self: str(self.problematic_object) if self.problematic_object!=None else "")
```

3:

```py
def __str__(self):
    return "string1" + str(self.object) + "\n" + "string2" + self.another_object + "\n" + "string3" + lambda self: str(self.problematic_object) if self.problematic_object!=None else ""
```

I get this error in all the cases:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I know that this can be done using a normal `if-else`, but is there any way I can do it using a `lambda`? This is my first time using a `lambda` and this kind of an `if-else`. What is the mistake I'm making? Can a `lambda` be used like this?

Comment: Show a stack trace in all cases. What is actually causing the error? Check for unclosed parens on the previous line btw

Comment: Can you add the lambda you are trying to use to your question please?

Comment: There's no reason I can see for using an anonymous function here. Use a ternary expression.

Comment: `lambda` creates an anonymous function object -- it needs to be called in order to return anything. This is not a situation where you should use a lambda, period.

Comment: I guess this is related too and is a way other than using f-strings: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19213688/16136190.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `self.problematic_object` is possibly `None`, and in that case you just want an empty string, simply use f-strings to add it to your overall string. No need for any boolean logic:

```py
def __str__(self):
    return f"string1{self.object}\nstring2{self.another_object}\nstring3{self.problematic_object}"
```

If `self.problematic_object` is `None` then nothing will be added to the end of the string. If it's not `None` then its value will be added.